# php URL rewrite works on apache, not 100% on a litespeed server

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, litespeed

I'm having a few problems getting a PHP script to work on a new server - I've gone from apache to a Litespeed server, and I can't get the little CMS to work on it.

In a nutshell the .htaccess contains:

```
 ServerName www.domain.co.uk
ServerAlias domain.co.uk
DocumentRoot /home/domain/public_html/
<Directory  /home/ttedomainpublic_html/>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain.co.uk [NC]
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.domain.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(admin|content|css|images|img|non_public|pdf|renderers|scripts|sendmail|templates) - [L]
</Directory>
```

And the index.php contains:

```
<?php
include("non_public/config.php");

// Get the request URI
$requestUri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$requestUri = preg_replace("~^/~","",$requestUri);
$requestUri = str_replace("/","_",$requestUri);


// Make sure that we'll get the index
if(empty($requestUri)) $requestUri = "index";

if(file_exists(ROOT_PATH . "content/" . $requestUri))
{
// Include the header
include(ROOT_PATH . "templates/header.php");

// Check if there's a renderer
if(file_exists(ROOT_PATH . "renderers/" . $requestUri . ".php"))
{
    include(ROOT_PATH . "renderers/" . $requestUri . ".php");
}
else
    echo file_get_contents(ROOT_PATH . "content/" . $requestUri);

// Include the footer
include(ROOT_PATH . "templates/footer.php");
}

else
    echo file_get_contents(ROOT_PATH . "content/404");
?>
```

So the above should throw a page together from the content file held in **content/**, a few bits and bobs from the template and some basic things from the **renderers/** directory.

I hope that makes sense so far? This has worked well on an Apache server for a few years, but just doesn't work under Litespeed. 
The current end result when you go to **www.domain.co.uk/notes** is simply a 404 page, because obviously **www.domain.co.uk/notes/index.php** etc. doesn't exist and the server can't seem to put the page together.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Many thanks...

Comment: Wow, zero response! :(
I guess litespeed servers are not too popular...

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling rewrite logging and visiting the page. The rewrite log should explain what's happening within the rewrite rules.